# I'm looking for this word that means showing understanding or assent but may be faux assent

Tags: vocabulary, adverbs

The word had been used with "nodding *[such-ly]*".  If I remember correctly, the person I heard this from was describing one of the attributes you needed to be a manager was to be able to listen to someone and "nod" this way, maybe rubbing your chin with your hand or something to signal to that person that you are listening (even if you're not).

There is even a Wikipedia article about this word, but I cannot remember it at all.

At 58-y.o., this is one of the few times i hear a new word i never heard before (and look it up). Unfortunately, i forgot it right after.

Comment: You can adverb these [Google]: ingratiating [adjective]
intended to gain approval or favor; sycophantic.
synonyms: sycophantic, toadying, fawning, unctuous, obsequious;

Comment: Disingenuous. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100677/word-for-person-willing-to-argue-contradictory-things-depending-on-what-suits-hi/100727#100727

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be "nodding *sagely*?"

Comment: actually the word was "sagaciously".  someone downvoted you, but i am canceling the down vote.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ways I could nod to show I'm listening: sympathetically, knowingly.

Ways I could nod to show I'm listening when I'm not really listening: automatically, absentmindedly.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be *acceptingly* or *appreciatively*?  Acceptance and appreciation do not imply adherence or assent.

Answer (score 0):

i wanted to put this in an answer, just so that people who may have read or contributed would see it pop into visibility.  the word i was looking for was "sagaciously".  i know it doesn't mean exactly what i took from it (from the context of usage), but normally when i hear of some manager or expert or someone "nodding sagaciously", there is an *appearance* of faux understanding or assent.

thanks everyone who answered and Erik for being the closest.